# GraphQL query works fine for one field but errors on the second?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

Im using Apollo Client 2. Im getting a result that seems really weird to me but I am new to GraphQL.

Ive set up a simple schema with 2 fields. When I query one of the fields it works find but the other one returns an error:

Schema:

```
type Query {
    hi: String
    groups: [Group]
}

type Group {
    name: String
    test: String
}
```

Resolvers:

```
Query: {
    hi() {
        return 'howdy';
    },
    groups() {
        // Here I'm mocking a database call 
        return [{ name: '1', test: 'test 1' }, { name: '2', test: 'test 2' }];
    },
},
```

In GraphiQL this query works:

```
{
  groups {
    name
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
 "data": {
    "groups": [
      {
        "name": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I query for the test field:

```
{
  groups {
    test
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"test\" on type \"Group\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The result you printed does not seem to come from your resolver. In your resolver you return name: "1", but the result shows **Kickboxing**. If it's not just for the example, maybe you're not calling the same server? .. and the second source doesn't have the `test` field?

Comment: Sorry thats a mistake. I started working with an actual database call and then mocked the call while debugging. I forgot to update my question, but I've done that now.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the GraphiQL page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to refresh the GraphiQL page. Doh!

UPDATE - I had the issue again and this time had to run graphiql in an incognito window. It seems browser caching can be an issue even if you refresh.

UPDATE 2 - This is probably a Meteor specific issue, but I need to edit a JavaScript file further up chain for changes in my resolvers and schema to picked up. Seems there are a lot of caching type headaches but I don't know if this is Meteor, Apollo or GraphQL.